# Reading core_properties using python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-2010, python-docx

I'm trying to read the last_saved_by attribute on docx files. I've followed the comments on Github, and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625022/reading-coreproperties-keywords-from-docx-file-with-python-docx). It seems that support has been added, but the documentation isn't very clear for me.

I've entered the following code into my script (Notepad++):

```
import docx

document = Document()
core_properties = document.core_properties
core_properties.author = 'Foo B. Baz'
document.save('new-filename.docx')
```

I only get an error message at the end:

```
NameError: name 'Document' is not defined
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. :(

When I enter it line by line through python itself, the problem seems to come up from the second line.

I'm using Python 3.4, and docx 0.8.6

Comment: I am guessing it is `docx.Document` or `docx.something.Document` instead of  just `Document`

Answer (score 2):

Figured out where I was going wrong, for those that want to know:

```
from docx import Document
import docx

document = Document('mine.docx')
core_properties = document.core_properties
print(core_properties.author)
```

There'll be a more succinct way of doing this, I'm sure (importing docx twice seems redundant for a start) - but it works, so I'm happy! :)

Comment: your second line is excess, your question is Document not found, but Document is in docx module, so you have two choices,one:`from docx import Document` and you can use Document("xxx") directly; second you can `import docx` and use `docx.Document("xxxx")`, but i strongly suggest you use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you need from the `docx` module is `Document`, then you only need to use

```
from docx import Document
```

If you use more than that, you could use

```
import docx
document = docx.Document()
```

importing specific names from the `docx` module is your choice; either way, you don't *need* to have two lines importing from (or importing) `docx`, although it's not expensive to have both.